# fa-user-circle-o not working

Tags: html, font-awesome

I want to show user circle icon, I have download a font-awesome css file with version 4.7.0.
But this is not working for me. If I use cdn then its working. I am not getting what is the issue in downloaded file.
Here my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Comment: It may be about "relative paths". Can  you share your css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can understand from it's name, Font-Awesome has cool font-based approach to use icons. So, including CSS file is not enough. If you want to store your CSS file locally, you should store font files too.

As [documented](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/), you should have entire folder (including fonts folder which includes woff, tff etc) on your server.

> 1. **Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project.**
> 2. In the  of your html, reference the location to your font-awesome.min.css.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with `body` part of HTML. Surely, it has to be with `font-awesome.min.css` or its path.

There are two ways to go about this problem:

1. `font-awesome.min.css` may not loaded along with your HTML. Check in `network` tab of chrome DevTools. The path you have provided indicates chrome to look for the CSS file in same directory as the HTML file.
2. Alternatively, you can provide `cdn` link for `font-awesome.min.css`, if you dont want to maintain the CSS by yourself. For this, change `link` tab in `head` to below:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to host the font files too. Go to the fontawesome website and read the related documentation.
[Font awesome get started](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/)